Why are session tokens and form tokens different laravel?
Why are session tokens and form tokens different in Laravel?
Added to file:
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php
protected function tokensMatch($request)
{ $token = $this->getTokenFromRequest($request);
echo '<br>X-CSRF-TOKEN:'.$request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN');
echo '<br>X-XSRF-TOKEN:'.$request->header('X-XSRF-TOKEN');
echo '<br>token:'.$request->input('_token');
echo '<br>sessionToken:'.$request->session()->token();  
    return is_string($request->session()->token()) &&
           is_string($token) &&
           hash_equals($request->session()->token(), $token);
}

As a result, the tokens do not match:
echo '<br>token:'.$request->input('_token');
echo '<br>sessionToken:'.$request->session()->token();

Gives an error, in the form added:
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="iqKfupuI0nXRuvCYQWneI4WRoGEoxcLB4z5J3dj0">

in the head too:
<meta name="csrf-token" content="iqKfupuI0nXRuvCYQWneI4WRoGEoxcLB4z5J3dj0">

When entering the form error TokenMismatchException
and they are different.
token:iqKfupuI0nXRuvCYQWneI4WRoGEoxcLB4z5J3dj0
sessionToken:yyWETkrykVrsGzhKsZVus3LgeYBxTjlr26IDfzor

what is the problem? the settings have not changed, nothing has changed.
gives an error, added in from:
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="iqKfupuI0nXRuvCYQWneI4WRoGEoxcLB4z5J3dj0"> in head too 
<meta name="csrf-token" content="iqKfupuI0nXRuvCYQWneI4WRoGEoxcLB4z5J3dj0"> 

When entering the form, the error is TokenMismatchException and they are different
token:iqKfupuI0nXRuvCYQWneI4WRoGEoxcLB4z5J3dj0 sessionToken:yyWETkrykVrsGzhKsZVus3LgeYBxTjlr26IDfzor 

what's the problem? The settings haven't changed, nothing has changed.
And I receive mistake TokenMismatchException.

What makes you think they should be equal? Also, please keep in mind that Laravel 5 is EOL since more than four years - it does not receive any security updates since then and should no longer be in use!

I dont know laravel, when i try to login in form a recieve  TokenMismatchException

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

@SergeyPermyakov sessionToken & csrf-token is two different thing.

You should understand what sessionToken & csrf-token

A session token (default name laravel_session) in Laravel refers to the session identifier uniquely representing a user's session.
A csrf-token is a security token that protects web applications from CSRF attacks.

